# Update MySQL table taking the value of a column, adding it to another column, the changing the value of the first column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table with the following code:

```
UPDATE balance_down SET earned_back=earned_back + charge_amount, charge_amount='0'
```

Basically I am trying to take the value of charge_amount, add it to earned back, and set the charge_amount to zero. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What happened when you ran your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right.
That's why your query works as expected.
But if you replace operands, you will get a wrong results:

```
SET charge_amount='0', earned_back=earned_back + charge_amount
```

So it evaluates in the specified order (from left to right).

Anyway, you always could split your query into two independent queries (set earned_back=earned_back + charge_amount, and then set charge_amount='0') just in order not to rely on evaluation order.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is clearer to have two queries.

```
UPDATE balance_down SET earned_back=earned_back + charge_amount;
UPDATE balance_down SET charge_amount='0';
```

This illustrates that you are incrementing the earned_back by the charge amount.  Then the charge amount goes to zero.  It's clear that the amount of the charge_amount is being applied in full.